# Google Analytics Filter Set of Pages

Tags: regex, filter, google-analytics, expression, analytics

I need to create a filter on Google Analytics to include only a set of pages, for example, the view will have a filter to collect data only from

```
www.example.com/page1.html
www.example.com/page2.html
www.example.com/page3.html
```

I am trying to achieve this by using a Custom Filter to Include - > Request URI and using a Regex on the Filter Pattern.
My problem is that the Regex exceeds the 255 character limitation, even after I tried to optimice the regex to be a small as possible.

Creating more than one Include Filter does not work because this way no data would be collected, so I am wondering how could I achieve this? Thank you

This is the original regex

```
/es/investigacion/lace\.html|/en/research/lace\.html|/es/investigacion/lace/programa-maestrias\.html|/es/investigacion/lace/alumni/latin-american-forum-entrepreneurs\.html|/es/investigacion/lace/alumni/fondo-angel-investment\.html|/es/investigacion/lace/alumni\.html|/es/investigacion/lace/fondo-inversion\.html|/es/investigacion/lace/investigacion\.html|/es/investigacion/lace/acerca-del-centro\.html|/es/investigacion/lace/alumni/estudiantes-del-pais\.html|/en/research/investigation\.html|/en/research/about-the-center\.html|/es/investigacion/lace/alumni/mentoring\.html|/es/investigacion/lace/alumni/reatu-entrepreneur-award\.html|/en/research/lace/master-program\.html|/en/research/lace/alumni\.html|/en/research/investment-fund\.html
```

Edit: first try to compress the regex

```
/es/investigacion/lace/(programa-maestrias|alumni|investigacion|programa-maestrias|alumni/latin-american-forum-entrepreneurs|alumni/fondo-angel-investment|fondo-inversion|investigacion|acerca-del-centro|alumni/estudiantes-del-pais|alumni/mentoring|alumni/incae-entrepreneur-award)\.html|
```

Edit: the reason for this is because I need to create a new user profile on GA, and this new profile will have access to the information of a set of URLs only; so what occurred to me is create a new View that only captures the information of this set of URLs, and then assign the profile to this view with "Read/Analyze" permissons.

Comment: Can you show us the regex you've used?

Comment: I have added it to the question

Answer (score 0):

There are definitely more ways to optimise the regex. For example, since all string options end with `.html`, you could do something like this:

```
/(es/investigacion/lace|en/research/lace)\.html
```

by taking the `.html` out.

You could also take out

```
/es/investigacion/lace
```

and weave in the variable part of that using `|`'s, eg.

```
/es/investigacion/lace/(programa-maestrias|alumni|investigacion)\.html
```

But try a few of those optimisation techniques and you should be able to fit more in.

Comment: Can use a character class too for the `en` directories, `/e[sn]/`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried to compress the regex by taking out the "/es/investigacion/lace" and ".html" ; and applying it only to the spanish URLs the regex is already 286 characters. Is there a way I can create a filter for the view to Include only a fixed set of URLs, without using a regex? Thank you.